# How to launch headless chrome in OS X

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver, headless, macos-big-sur, webautomation

I am trying to launch Chrome in Headless mode for some automation with Selenium and Python. I've tried all the arguments but Chrome will not launch in headless mode. Please help. Chrome will launch with all the arguments except for headless.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager 
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
options = Options()
options.add_argument("--headless")
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
options.add_argument('--no-proxy-server')
options.add_argument("--proxy-server='direct://'")
options.add_argument("--proxy-bypass-list=*")
options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
options.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
options.binary_location = "/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome"
#options.headless = True
#options.add_argument("--window-size=780,620")
#options.add_argument("--headless")
#options.add_argument("--ignore-certificate-errors")
#options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
#options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options = options, executable_path= "/Users/chromedriver")
driver.get("https://www.google.com")
print ("Headless Chrome Initialized")
```

Comment: First sentiment of debugging:  what is the error message you see when you launch it in headless mode?

Comment: I don't see an error message. I see Chrome icon popping up in the dock and disappearing/closing in an instant. The print message then comes up in the console.

Answer (score 0):

That worked for me before some months:

```
options = Options()
options.add_argument("headless")
options.add_argument("--start-minimized")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r'C:\path\to\chromedriver.exe')
```

or

```
options = Options()
options.headless = True
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r'C:\path\to\chromedriver.exe')
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried this but it doesn't seem to be having an effect.

Comment: Sorry headless works fine in windows and ubuntu ,sadly cant test on mac.Maybe you can try phantomJS that is by default headless.

Comment: I tried it on my windows 10 VM and I get the same result. I see Chrome icon popping up in the taskbar and disappearing/closing in an instant. The print message then comes up in the console.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's what headless does. As long as you don't see the window and the browser works, it should mean all is good

Comment: Ah I see. I am using the headless mode to capture a screenshot further down in the process of the automation. wonder how I would do that?

Comment: phantomJS is dead for 5 years already. Don't try to put people on the wrong track. Replied to thee comment above https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66323003/how-to-launch-headless-chrome-in-os-x#comment117254381_66323078

Comment: @intrepid_prgmer ask the question about screenshot taking in a new question please. It would be answered faster.

Answer (score 0):

That's what headless mode actually does. It shows chrome browser running but since you run it in headless mode - there is no UI and that's fine. If your tests pass in headless mode - it's ok.